# Laravel 8: Multiple Select Option Sends Empty Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables at db, one of them is named `users` which simply contains user information of website and the other one is `tags` which contains some hashtags that users can choose from them.

I also created a table named `tag_user` that can store the `tag_id` and `user_id` like this image:

[image]

(just like Stackoverflow that a user can select multiple tags such as *php*, *javascript* & etc)

So in order to make this relationship between these two, I added this to `User` model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

And also this one to `Tag` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

And here is the select option on blade, and users can select multiple tags from db:

```
<select class="form-control BSinaBold" name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple>
    @foreach(\App\Models\Tag::all() as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" {{ in_array($tag->id , Auth::user()->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Then at the Controller, I added this in order to update data at `tags` table:

```
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
{
    $validate_data = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'job' => 'nullable',
        'stackoverflow' => 'nullable',
        'github' => 'nullable',
        'instagram' => 'nullable',
        'linkedin' => 'nullable',
        'website' => 'nullable',
        'location' => 'nullable',
        'skills' => 'array',
    ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($profile);

    $user->update([
        'job' => request('job'),
        'stackoverflow' => request('stackoverflow'),
        'github' => request('github'),
        'instagram' => request('instagram'),
        'linkedin' => request('linkedin'),
        'website' => request('website'),
        'location' => request('location'),
    ]);

    $user->tags()->sync(request('skills'));

    $user->save();

    return view('profile');
}
```

And it works fine and perfect but the only problem is this line, that does not sync data at `tags` table:

`$user->tags()->sync(request('skills'));`

So I tried debugging and I found out that `request('skills')` is EMPTY!

So the question is, why it does not send any data to the Controller?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:**

[image]

Comment: Is `request('skills')` empty every time or only empty when nothing is selected?

Comment: @İbrahimDoğan When I select some options, it is empty.

Comment: can you check post data from browsers network? are you sure that it is sending that parameter with the request?

Comment: @İbrahimDoğan I can update other data except this select option. Meaning the request can be sent!

Comment: Yes the others are sending sure, but it will be better if you see skills[] in your post data, you can open inspect>network and then click submit to check request over your browser.

Comment: @İbrahimDoğan I did what you said and I updated my question with a picture of it

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the blade/html for the form?

Comment: @tejoslaeslio seems like you are getting a 500 error, can you update the question with the laravel log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the skills array is not being posted correctly on the form submission, then there could just be a simple problem with the form. Are you posting normally or using an AJAX call? Do you have a conflicting field on the form called 'skills' like a hidden input? Is the skills field located within the `<form>` tag?

Otherwise, if the browser is in fact posting the skills correctly but just not being read correctly by the request (unlikely), how about you try to switch your request helper functions `request()` to use the `$request` object that was passed into your function. IDK, but maybe it will work differently by some chance since we can't see all your code.

Also note that the validation function isn't doing much of anything since nothing is required.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($profile);

    $user->update([
                      'job' => $request->input('job', null),
                      'stackoverflow' => $request->input('stackoverflow', null),
                      'github' => $request->input('github', null),
                      'instagram' => $request->input('instagram', null),
                      'linkedin' => $request->input('linkedin', null),
                      'website' => $request->input('website', null),
                      'location' => $request->input('location', null),
                  ]);

    $user->tags()->sync($request->input('skills', []));

    // I don't think you need this since update & sync trigger saving
    // $user->save();

    return view('profile');
}
```

If you want to see all the data getting posted you can just dump or log the data for debugging:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
{
    Log::debug($request->all());
    dd($request->all());

...
```